image failed to show when Upload from Lambda
if run my code from run on localhost then upload to AWS-lambda then if i use the link on browser it will show the image but if i deploy to lambda then upload it, it will not show the image..
i have this code that upload
func UploadFile(uploader *manager.Uploader, key string, file multipart.File, fileHeader *multipart.FileHeader) (string, error) {

    if file == nil {
        return "", errors.New("file is nil")
    }

    contentType := fileHeader.Header.Get("Content-Type")
    if contentType == "" {
        contentType = "application/octet-stream" // Default to binary if content type is not provided
    }

    fileStat, err := fileHeader.Open()
    if err != nil {
        return "", fmt.Errorf("failed to open file for debugging: %w", err)
    }
    defer fileStat.Close()

    if _, err := file.Seek(0, 0); err != nil {
        return "", errors.New("failed to reset file cursor: " + err.Error())
    }

    result, err := uploader.Upload(context.TODO(), &s3.PutObjectInput{
        Bucket:      aws.String("unleap-bucket"),
        Key:         aws.String("uneleap/" + key),
        Body:        file,
        ContentType: aws.String(contentType),
        ACL:         types.ObjectCannedACLPublicRead,
    })

    if err != nil {
        return "", err
    }
    // Ensure the result is not nil and return the location of the uploaded file
    if result == nil || result.Location == "" {
        return "", errors.New("failed to get the uploaded file location")
    }
    return result.Location, err
}

this is kind of surprise to me,
if i upload from localhost link will show but if i upload from lambda it will not show
here is my serverless file
service: uneleap-api-client

frameworkVersion: ">=4.1.19"


provider:
  name: aws
  region: eu-north-1
  runtime: go1.x
  stage: ${opt:stage}
  iam:
    role:
      statements:
        - Effect: "Allow"
          Action:
            - "s3:PutObject"
            - "s3:GetObject"
            - "s3:PutObjectAcl"
          Resource: "arn:aws:s3:::u-bucket/*"

custom:
  hooks:
    'package:initialize': ./scripts/generate_swagger.sh

package:
  patterns:
    - '!*/**'
    - bin/main

functions:
  api:
    handler: bin/main
    events:
      - http:
          path: /{proxy+}
          method: ANY
          cors: true

i added this after a long search but yet no solution
iam:
        role:
          statements:
            - Effect: "Allow"
              Action:
                - "s3:PutObject"
                - "s3:GetObject"
                - "s3:PutObjectAcl"
              Resource: "arn:aws:s3:::u-bucket/*"



When you check your S3 bucket using the AWS web console, do you see the image file uploaded there? 2) When you open the DevTools in your browser, what does it tell you about accessing the image's URL when you click the link? I mean, you should employ the standard engineering tactic when facing a problem which is decomposition of the problem space: you identify what can go wrong and check each possibility in turn, ruling out them one by one.


@kostix i already solve it... is just for me to add multipath-form to the Api gatway media
thanks

Glad to know you fixed it! You are welcome to add your own Answer to assist future readers.

@JohnRotenstein i have done that

Add multipart/form-data to your binary media type..
so go to Api Gateway then click the Api you are using, then click Api settings at the left hand conner then add it

